# Copying text in vim to the global clipboard

Tags: macos, vi

On my linux computer I am able to copy text to the clipboard with the command `"+y`. How do I do the same on Mac?

Answer (score 4):

macOS version of **vim** is compiled with `-clipboard` (you can check with `vim --version`). So there's no shared clipboard available. In this case you can download/recompile new **vim** or you can use system command `pbcopy` ([man page](https://developer.apple.com/legacy/library/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/pbcopy.1.html)). Here's how to use it as <kbd>CTRL ⌃</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> shortcut:

`map <C-c> y:e ~/clipsongzboard<CR>P:w !pbcopy<CR><CR>:bdelete!<CR>`

Add this to your `~/.vimrc` file.

Explanation of this command can be found here: [vimtips @ quora](https://vimtips.quora.com/How-to-Copy-to-clipboard-on-vim)

Comment: why would they do that ?? now I have to recompile from source

Comment: In `Big Sur` it is compiled with `+clipboard`

Answer (score 2):

Additionally you can install the program [MacVim](http://macvim-dev.github.io/macvim/), which is a version of Vim 8 compiled for Mac, including a GUI. However you don't need the GUI, you can just link the `mvim` executable to `vim` somewhere on your `$PATH`, and the `+` register will work as your clipboard just like you are used to.

MacVim is also recommended if you are going to install some recent plugins like YouCompleteMe.